# Is it idiomatic to say "the goal is to serve as"?

Tags: idioms

A post says

> The goal of this post **is to serve as** a nice introduction to ...

which appears to use a pattern "the goal is to serve as".

With the meaning of "an aim or purpose", [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/goal) gives these examples

> My goal is to lose ten pounds before the summer.
>
> They have set themselves a series of goals to achieve by the end of the month.

which appears to use another pattern "the goal is to do something".

Oxford Dictionary does not give similar examples.

So, is it idiomatic to say "the goal is to serve as"? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it's not. "The goal of [something] is to serve as..." is, though I'm not sure about the technical reasons why.

Comment: The proximity of *goal* and *post* is unfortunate! And no, it isn't quite idiomatic. It is like saying "Our aim is to aim to be an introduction." "The purpose of this post is to introduce..." would be better.